# Laravel 6.x update Amazon SES stopped working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I just updated my Laravel application from 5.8.x to 6.18.x. I also updated the ENV name declaration to reflect the new Laravel pattern.

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.

I set AWS_DEFAULT_REGION to **eu-west-1** since I am using `eu-west-1.amazonses.com` in the SES setup.

But when I try to send an email now, I get: `Error executing "SendRawEmail" on "https://email.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"` even though eu-central-1 is nowhere declared inside my app. I've been trying to wrap my head around this for a while now, but cannot find a solution.

Also, it seems like AWS wants me to verify the to address, which is even more confusing. I've been out of the sandbox for over 2 years and on the live server with the older Laravel instance the mail still works just fine.

I have no actual code, since this is just stuff in my ENV file and this inside my config/services.php file:

```
'ses' => [
    'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
],
```

I really don't know what else I could check.

Comment: Are you sure the AWS credential is working? Is there any chance that your ec2 instance is running on `eu-central-1` instance.

Comment: @ArunK I'm not running a EC2 instance. And like I said, it's still working fine on the old installation.

Comment: Amazon has changed some settings. Especially related to encrypted data. (The 'S' in whatever protocol.)
You may want to log in. There could be a remark on the top right. Click on it and see if you need to change something. In my case I didn't have to. The SSL/TLS authority has changed. Amazon can issue their own certificates now. If that is the reason for your issue I don't know. But I believe it is worth mentioning it to you.

Comment: Another thing you may check is the IAM settings for this particular service. You may have given the wrong region access. I don't believe this is the case for you, but you never know. I had a similar issue once because of a general setting in the region I was using changed some accessibilities. I didn't think it was going to affect me, but it was. If that's your case, go to IAM, click on the one you use for SES and if there is an issue, you'll quickly learn.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you set the region directly on `config/services.php` and see if it works. If it works, I would check why the values set on the environment file is not passing down the chain.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already tried that, AWS still wants to use the eu-central region. I checked ALL the files, even the vendor folder but this region is not set anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your suggestions. The problem was actually not AWS related. After the upgrade from 5.8 to 6.x the old .env file was still used. So any changes I did to the .env file were not used. I don't know why though, as I cleared all caches and config files after the upgrade. But it's working again now.